# Passing in variables from Terraform to Ansible with spaces

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2, terraform

Currently I have a tfvars file in json setting key values with spaces. For example:

```
{
  "customer": "Test Customer",
}
```

I then pass this variable to a ansible playbook command run locally on the provisioned EC2 host using cloud-config

`sudo ansible-playbook /Playbook.yml --extra-vars 'customer=${var.customer}'`

In that playbook I have a license file that I want to propagate with Ansible's template module. Currently the license file will get Test, but not Test Customer (because of the space). How can I fix this?

Also on a second note, is there a better/cleaner way of passing in terraform variables to a ansible playbook command in a Terraform config other than -e extra variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick for you:

```
sudo ansible-playbook /Playbook.yml --extra-vars "customer='${var.customer}'"
```

Note: 
I would really recommend you, for a better design, to decouple these two tools from each other. Don't make a tight coupling between ansible and terraform, as in the future you may decide to start using a different tool which will force you to rewrite your whole IaC.

Comment: I actually agree with you, although I'm not quite sure the best way to go about decoupling it, at least a little bit. The instances that I spin up with Terraform require post configuration which I am doing with the Ansible playbook. How would you go about it?

Comment: I would still keep the post configuration responsibilty by ansible. I agree that you can't decouple them totally, but when thinking for the future, don't use the same variables files for both tools (as I understand yoy did by your post). By the way, did my answer helped you to resolve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Gilad,

Your comment did work for passing in the full string so thank you for that. I have upvoted it. However another issue I am now facing is passing in a number. Would you happen to know how to do that? I am trying to use the jsonencode function and passing in the variables now as json, but that still isn't working.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I suggest you to open a different post regarding this(and submit the answer I supplied helped you resolving this post), as this is a different issue. So please create a new post with all the details and I'll help you.

Comment: I did and ended up finding the answer. Thanks for all your help Gilad!